# Seeking references about the Principle Of Implosion (verum ex quodlibet), $B\vDash A\vee\neg A $

Tags: logic, reference-request, math-history

A well-known valid principle in classical logic is the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), also called "ex falso quodlibet". This principle states that everything follows from a contradiction:

$$A \wedge \neg A \vDash B$$

Everything about this principle intrigues me, but yesterday when I was reading some articles on this subject, I came across something I had never heard of before: the principle of implosion (verum ex quodlibet). If I properly understood it states that a tautology follows from anything:

$$B \vDash A \vee \neg A $$

> Because I am very curious about learning more about this so called principle of implosion, I am looking for more information, articles or books on this subject.

Comment: Isn't this the _definition_ of tautology, that is, a proposition that does not depend on premises?

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to know?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I want to know if there are more articles or books about this principle. I don't have a specific question, but for example I would like to know some more about the validity of this principle in intuitionistic logic since there are many articles about the principle of explosion in intuitionistic logic, but I cannot find many articles about this principle of implosion.

Comment: As per my answer, the principle is a straightforward consequence of the definition of *valid* consequence: a tautology is always true; thus, it is true in every case where a sentence $B$ is true, for $B$ whatever. It is intuitionistically valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know this is an old post, but how can this be intuitionistically valid? Intuitionists don't take A∨¬A to be a tautology, do they? If B⊨A∨¬A were valid then everything is true or false, yet denying this is the motivation behind denying LEM.

Answer (score 2):

See[Medieval Theories of Consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-medieval/#BurOck) and [John Buridan(ca.1300-ca.1360)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buridan/#Log)'s [Tractatus de consequentiis](https://books.google.it/books?id=zJKUDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) for  the definition of *consequence* in terms of truth-preservation, and the formulation of some general principles following from the definition, such as that :

> from every impossible proposition any other follows and every necessary proposition follows from any other (First conclusion).

See also another edition: [Jean Buridan’s Logic: The Treatise on Supposition The Treatise on Consequences (Reidel, 1985)](https://books.google.it/books?id=6CbpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA196): First theorem.

Answer (score 2):

(I can't give you any references, but the following may help clarify your thinking on this topic.)

**The Principle of EXPLOSION**

$~~~~ A\land \neg A \implies B$

The Truth Table:

[image]

Proof based on a form of natural deduction:

[image]

---

**The Principle of IMPLOSION**

$~~~~B\implies (A\implies B)$

The Truth Table:

[image]

Proof based on a form of natural deduction:

[image]

---

(Related topic)

**The Principle of VACUOUS TRUTH**

$~~~~ A\implies [\neg A \implies B]$

The Truth Table:

[image]

Proof based on a form of natural deduction:

[image]